# How to handle fill toggle with mouseover / mouseout events on group

Tags: konvajs

In jquery we have toggles for this.

If I am doing it jquery DIY I would stash the 'on' and 'off' fill colors in a 'data' attribute of the element and retrieve each as needed.

What is an efficient method to effect a mouseover fill color toggle in Konva?

Example: Say I have a layer, and on this I have a group containing a rect. A mouseover and mouseout switcharoo to highlight the rect by changing its fill color on mouseover and back to normal on mouseexit might be

```
rect.on('mouseover', function(evt){
  var shape = evt.target;
  // Uh-oh, I need to stash the current fill color somewhere 
  shape.fill('lime');

})
rect.on('mouseexit', function(evt){
  var shape = evt.target;
  shape.fill('that_stashed_fill_color');  // < how to get the stashed val and from where ?
})
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: My own attempt was to use

```
rect.on('mouseover', function(evt){
  var shape = evt.target;
  $(shape).data('bgColor', shape.fill()); // stash current in data
  shape.fill('lime');    
})

rect.on('mouseexit', function(evt){
  var shape = evt.target;
  shape.fill($(shape).data('bgColor'));  // get the stashed val from jq data
})
```

which works but the use of the jq wrapper feels like an overhead I would prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use almost any custom attribute in Konva nodes (make sure you don't overlap with existing properties, so you don't have an unexpected result). Set - `shape.setAttr('anyAttibute', anyValue);` get - `shape.getAttr('anyAttibute');`

You can do this:

```
rect.on('mouseenter', function(evt){
  var shape = evt.target;
  shape.setAttr('oldFill', shape.fill());
  // set new fill
  shape.fill('lime');
  shape.getLayer().batchDraw();
})
rect.on('mouseleave', function(evt){
  var shape = evt.target;
  shape.fill(shape.getAttr('oldFill')); 
  shape.getLayer().batchDraw();
})
```

But personally I prefer to use this:

```
const FILL_COLOR = 'red';
const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 'lime';

shape.fill(FILL_COLOR);
shape.on('mouseenter', function(evt){
  shape.fill(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
})
shape.on('mouseleave', function(evt){
  shape.fill(FILL_COLOR); 
})
```